# Creating a custom Ninject provider for multiple types implementing the same interface

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have an interface, let's say it's `IDrawingTool`. I have multiple classes implementing this interface, let's say `PencilTool`, `PenTool`, `YellowMarkerTool`, etc. I am usually binding more than one of these classes in Ninject, and I always access `IDrawingTool` instances by calling `kernel.GetAll<IDrawingTool>`. So far so good.

Now, I want to create a new `IDrawingTool` implementation, `ConfigurableBrushTool`, that can be configured in many different ways (let's say brush color, brush thickness, etc).

I'd like to be able to have some sort of a "factory"/"provider" that will let me inject multiple `IDrawingTool`s (i.e. multiple `ConfigurableBrushTool`s with different configurations). That is, I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
kernel.Bind<IDrawingTool>.To<PencilTool>();
kernel.Bind<IDrawingTool>.To<PenTool>();
kernel.Bind<IDrawingTool>.ToTypeProvider<ConfigurableBrushToolProvider>();
//...where ConfigurableBrushToolProvider reads e.g. 50 different
//brush configurations (color, thickness, etc) from the database/file/network/whatever
//and binds 50 different ConfigurableBrushTool instances.
//Of course, .ToTypeProvider() doesn't really exist :)

//Later on:
var tools = kernel.GetAll<IDrawingTool>(); //Should return pencil, pen and all 50 brushes
```

I haven't been able to find a way to make this happen with Ninject.

I've looked at implementing `IProvider` / `Provider<T>`, but it only lets me return one instance of the type I'm providing, there's no way to return multiple instances in bulk.

I've also looked at `IMissingBindingResolver`, and it's very close to what I need: If I create such a resolver for `IDrawingTool`, I am able to return multiple bindings for multiple `ConfigurableBrushTool`s. However, it only works if the binding is **missing** (i.e. if there are no other `IDrawingTool` bindings). As soon as I add my `PenTool` and `PencilTool` bindings, the binding for `IDrawingTool` is no longer "missing" and so my custom resolver is no longer invoked.

Is there a way to make my scenario happen? I.e. how can I bind an interface to both (1) specific types implementing the interface, and (2) a "factory"/"provider" of many instances that implement the interface, such that `GetAll` will return all of the bindings, both (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, looks like there is no `OOTB` feature to make multiple bindings from one binding set in module (at least I didn't find any obvious one).
Secondly, I managed to create some `PoC` with custom Kernel that allows you to create one-to-many binding with one .Bind.To call. Is is based on overriding `IKernel.GetBindings(..)` method and finding all bindings with special parameter. Then we can remove them, replacing by amount of custom generated.
However, I think such logic will have huge impact on performance if not carefully optimized (which is not done for `PoC` anyway) and should make it to production only if it is really needed. This `PoC` you can find [here](https://github.com/quanzi-ru/Ninject-dynamic-bindings).
As for me, it is much better approach to refactor existing code to inject a factory returning array created on-the-fly.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad there's no out-of-the-box way to do it... I appreciate the work you've put into this, despite the perf concerns your code achieves exactly what I need (though realistically I'll probably choose the refactoring approach), but in any case, bounty's yours.

Comment: Thanks, Eugene, hope this example would anyway help you to understand possibilities of Ninject.

Answer (score 0):

How about binding a custom collection (circumventing multi-injection) like:

```
public interface IToolList : IReadOnlyList<IDrawingTool> {}
```

and have it's implementation return both, bound tools and the ones "created" from database, something like:

```
public class ToolList : List<IDrawingTool>, IToolList
{
    public ToolList(IDrawingTool[] boundTools,... otherDependencies)
    {
       ... create all tools here
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a large, existing codebase which already does GetAll<IDrawingTool> in a bunch of places - I'd rather not change all these places to use IToolList (also, another developer down the line won't know that in the special case of IDrawingTool you need to access it via IToolList rather than just the standard GetAll). To be clear, my real use case is not about drawing tools but complex business objects : ), an there are many more things Ninject-ed. Your answer works as a workaround, but I'd like to know if it's possible to make Ninject do precisely what I need.